# Submit button in form - apply JavaScript check on click?

Tags: html, button, onclick

I have a button and a textfield in a form and when its clicked the form posts to another page. Is it possible to have some JavaScript function that checks if the textfield contains a value when the button is clicked? What I want is to display a message (alert box) if the button is clicked but the field is empty. The button should only submit if the field is filled. Possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This is basic Javascript, not related to html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible. It's even the very basics of web development.
Look at this link to learn how to validate data before submitting:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools for reference - see http://w3fools.com for reasons why. Actually the page you linked to immediately shouts "EWW" in my face: The value of a form field is never `null`. And if it *was* possible, the second example would break since it would possibly call `null.indexOf()`...

Comment: I agree with this manifesto's idea (thx to point it), but I think it's going a little bit too far to say w3schools is so harmful we shouldn't even mention it :)